# How to reverse a string in c using integers as indices?(without the use of strlen() or other string libraries)

Tags: c, string, reverse

I want to reverse a string using a function. Here is the program I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_string(char array[50]) {
    int lastindex, j;
    int i;
    char temp;
    for (j = 0; j <= 49; j++) {
        if (array[j] == '\0') {  \\access the index for null character
            break;
        }
        if (j != 0) {                                             
            lastindex = j - 1;  \\get last index of character string
        } else {
            lastindex = 0;
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= lastindex; i++) {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[lastindex];
            array[lastindex] = temp;
            lastindex--;
        }
        array[i + 1] = '\0';
    }
}

int main() {
    char myarray[500] = "Meglovania";
    reverse_string(myarray);
    printf("%s", myarray);
    return 0;
}
```

However,I got the wrong output: `Me`

I want to know how I can reverse a string without the explicit use of pointers.

Comment: Why are there two loops in your code? You only need one. Count up and down in a single loop and just swap characters.  There's loads of examples out there, include here at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+How+to+reverse+a+string%3F

Comment: Or are you not allowed to use `strlen()`? If not then write a `StringLength()` function of your own.

Comment: You've got `i++;` in two places in your loop.

Comment: What else than integers would you use as indexes?

Comment: @jwdonahue I tried that but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wanted to use integers specifically for indexing through an array. One could also use pointers

Comment: See my answer below. I commented out two lines of your code. That should get you a lot closer.

Comment: I think a little more care and consistency with the formatting would have alerted you to at least one of the problems with this code. You should also see this as a great opportunity to start learning how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out the extra `i++`. And because `i` ends up somewhere near the middle of the string, that's not where you want to drop a null character. Remember the string you're passing into the function is already null terminated.

Also, if `i == lastindex` then a swap is not necessary.

```
    //for(i=0;i<=lastindex;i++){
      for(i=0;i<lastindex;i++){
        temp = array[i];
        array[i]= array[lastindex];
        array[lastindex]=temp;
        //i++;
        lastindex--;
    }
    //array[i+1]='\0';
```

As @r3mainer points out, your code formatting was bad. You had one loop inside the other. I had to paste the whole thing into my IDE and build it, to run-down the remaining issues. This works:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse_string(char array[50])
{   int lastindex,j;
    int i;
    char temp;
    
    for(j = 0;j<=49;j++){
        
        if(array[j]=='\0'){
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(j!=0){                                             
        lastindex = j-1;

    }   
    else{
        lastindex = 0;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<lastindex;i++){
        temp = array[i];
        array[i]= array[lastindex];
        array[lastindex]=temp;
        lastindex--;
    }
    //array[i+1]='\0'; 
}

int main()

{
    char myarray[500]="Meglovania";
    reverse_string(myarray);
    printf("%s",myarray);
    return 0;

}
```

And this is easier on the eyes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int string_length(char *array)
{
    int counter = 0; // Doubles as an index.

    while('\0' != array[counter]) counter++;

    return counter;
}

void reverse_string(char array[50])
{
    int i;
    char temp;
    int lastIndex = string_length(array) - 1;
        
    for(i=0;i<lastIndex;i++){
        temp = array[i];
        array[i]= array[lastIndex];
        array[lastIndex]=temp;
        lastIndex--;
    }
}

int main()

{
    char myarray[50]="Meglovania";
    reverse_string(myarray);
    printf("%s",myarray);
    return 0;

}
```

You had string length code embedded in your reverse code and that's just bad practice. A function should generally do just one thing and call other functions if it needs other values, so I created a `string_length` function, initially with your version of the code, but I just couldn't abide by it, so clean that up as well.

I hope you've learned something from this exercise. Code formatting is very important. Every time you enter an open brace '{' in your code, immediately add the closing brace `}`, then insert whatever code you need in between them.

Comment: And what exactly were the result? "Does'nt work" is not a good problem statement.

Comment: This was the output I got after updating : `iaogMelvna`

Comment: Hmm... well you have ten characters now, that's an improvement, but you modified your MCVE and broke it. Try my fix on your originally posted code.

Comment: @plain-rice, I've updated my answer with some final advice and code examples based on your own.  Good luck with your assignment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.I will debug my code better next time.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the string using index variables, you can use an index starting at `0` and another one staring from the end of the string, swap characters at these positions and increment the first index and decrement the second, iterating while these positions don't coincide.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse_string(char *str) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str[j] != '\0') {
         j++;
    }
    while (i <-- j) {
        char c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char myarray[] = "Meglovania";
    printf("%s\n", reverse_string(myarray));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str, *wrk = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*(end + 1)) end++;
        while(end > wrk) 
        {
            char tmp = *end; 
            *end-- = *wrk; 
            *wrk++ = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", reverse((char[]){"1234567890"}));
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This should do it

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <string.h> // strlen

void reverse_string(char string[], size_t len) {
    if (len < 1) return;
    size_t front = 0, back = len - 1;
    char temp;
    while (front < back) {
        temp = string[front];
        string[front++] = string[back];
        string[back--] = temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    char string[500] = "sample string";
    reverse_string(string, strlen(string));
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should be trying the help the OP with _their_ code, not copy/pasting code you found on the internet.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I want to do it without strlen()

Comment: @jwdonahue I didn't copy and paste the code. I wrote it myself. But you're right, I should have taken the time to read through their code. My goal was to show them a more efficient way of solving their problem.